# In Visual Studio 2012 what is the Navigate backward shortcut on a french keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

It's been a while since I wonder how to navigate backward and forward in Visual Studio using a **French (fr-FR)** keyboard.

Hovering over the buttons it looks like this :

[image: Navigate Backward]

- Navigate backward: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
- Navigate forward: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

But I can't find the shortcuts! I guess <kbd>.</kbd> means dot but <strike>I'm not sure about it</strike> I am pretty sure it is not, see edit below.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

**Edit :**
Notice that this is not a common <kbd>.</kbd>, see image below, the shortcut is mapped to some kind of middle floating dot.

[image: Probably not a common dot]!

Comment: @Collin Funny you :) And you, have you tried it ?

Comment: I don't have a fr-FR keyboard handy, but you say it looks like a `.`, so does `Ctrl`+`.` do anything?

Comment: `Ctrl + .` does nothing or I wouldn't have asked :). If you want to try yourself, it's easy to get a logical fr-FR keyboard : just type the following command `control intl.cpl` and add it ! Then just switch to it using `Alt + Shift`.

Comment: I only ask because there are many questions that pop up here where the original poster didn't think to try it out! I'm not sure what else to try, but good luck!

Comment: Try the english layout, don't see a reason for it to be different: `Ctrl + -` and `Ctrl + Shift + -`.

Comment: Does it look like a hollow dot? What I mean is... Are your referring to the DEGREE symbol?

Comment: @icepack using the english layout works well. But I would like to know how to do that with my french layout.

Comment: @ZafKhan I don't think it's the degree symbol. Plus, using a French layout the degree symbol requires SHIFT (see SimonMourier contribution) so it couldnt' be accessed.

Comment: Why not just change the shortcut to something that works for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all keys can be used in Visual Studio shortcut keys. You can try it yourself in the Options dialog / Environment / Keyboard tab, in the 'Press shortcut keys' text box. For example, with a french keyboard, you just can't create the `CTRL+.` shortcut, you can't either create the `CTRL+-` shortcut (as some non french suggested :-)

Why? Because `CTRL+.` is just seen as `CTRL+SHIFT+;` (you have to look at a french keyboard to understand that) because Visual Studio extracts the SHIFT from the key pressed (because it wants to keep it as part of the shortcut), and doesn't remember a '.' character was pressed.

[image]
*(original image courtesy of [AZERTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY))*

The rule could be something like this:

> A Visual Studio shortcut is not recognized or cannot be used on a
>   given keyboard if the part of it that is not a modifier (CTRL, ALT,
>   SHIFT) cannot be created without using a modifier key on this
>   keyboard.

Note: there are some (probably hardcoded?) exceptions to this rule, for example, numbers 0 to 9 are usable without using SHIFT on a french keyboard...

Comment: Nice contribution but see my edit as I am now pretty sure that the shortcut is not mapped to a _regular_ dot.

Comment: @hoang - That doesn't change anything. There is a set of characters that are not usable as shortcuts for Visual Studio for a given keyboard layout.

Comment: I agree. I submitted a bug on Microsoft Connect regarding this unreachable shortcut. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/785825/impossible-de-naviguer-dans-visual-studio-avec-les-raccourcis-clavier-sur-un-clavier-fran-ais#

Comment: Very nice contribution, after hours spended to find this fu*****ng shortcut on my AZERTY keyboard, i have always remappedto anothet shortuct.But now.... i am sur it is worthless to waste time on finding it ;) TY

Answer (score 1):

In VS2012, you can go to `Tools`, `Options`, `Environment` and see the keyboard mappings for all of the available commands.

For example:

[image]

If you look at this on your French language system, you should see what mapping is enabled.

On my (English) system, it's `CTRL`+`-` (minus).

Comment: Nice workaround. See my edit, you helped me notice that it is not mapped to a _regular_ dot

Answer (score 1):

If it is not a normal fullstop `.` here is how I would go about identifying it.

1. Use [SysExporter](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sysexp.html) to copy the text out of the UI control in the VS2012 options menu.
2. Paste the text into a Unicode text file, such as one made with Windows Notepad or [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html). Be sure to save as Unicode.
3. Then open it with an editor such as [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) to open and copy the raw Unicode character value. Now you can look that up and find out exactly what symbol that dot is, and how to recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it, but I am not sure. 
I can't seem to actually test this on my computer, but what I did:

1. Used Pat or JK's Spy (http://patorjk.com/blog/software/) to extract the text from the combo box.
2. Copied that weird dot to python and did ord('·') and got 250
3. 250 = 0xfa, Edit: after doing some more research, I figured it can be also 183
4. 0xfa = ù ( or 0xb7, after doing some research on this)

<strike>So, I conclude that ctrl+shift+ù should work..</strike> 
It is the ' or " key on the English keyboard. (% on the french keyboard)

On my computer it didn't work, but worth the shot, maybe it will help.

**Edit:** 
Well after doing some research, I figured it is probably a bug.
After reading this: http://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=17600.0 and all other links in that link, and more about the "middle dot" (interpunct) I concluded that it is just not possible to type that character, not even using Japanese layout (http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081215222938AA9Nz0t)

I tried Spanish, Catalan, 4 different French layouts and Japanese.
Couldn't get that middle dot!
So, there seems to be only one explanation for this - it is truly a bug.

Comment: @hoang, did you try this? did you try "debuging" it somehow?

Comment: Thanks for your investigation :). But I tried CTRL+ù and it doesn't work :|

Comment: ok, worth the shot. if microsoft answer you, it would be nice to hear more about it

Answer (score 1):

As a french user, I have had this problem too and VS2015 won't solve it.
The quickest solution I found is simply to remap the command.

Go to

Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

and search for the commands View.NavigateBackward or View.NavigateForward and enter the new keyboard mapping.
It's tough to find one that is not already assigned to a command !
I personnaly use `Ctrl + Num .` for backward navigation and `Ctrl + Num 0, Ctrl + Num .` for forward navigation.

Better than having a default mapping that doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, I recommend Ctrl+Alt+left_arrow and Ctrl+Alt+right_arrow instead (as a french user also).

Answer (score 0):

Try `Ctrl + :` as `:` is where the `.` is on English keyboard.

Comment: I have already tried that to no avail. See my comment on how to set up a fr-FR keyboard if you want to try yourself.

Answer (score 0):

for a quick update for french/azerty users, on VS2015, the shortcuts ctrl+! and Ctrl+Shift+! are free and are closer to the home row.