# How do you "Navigate Backward" and "Navigate Forward" using the keyboard in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut

This may seem like a simple question but I have been using Visual Studio (different editions but Professional mostly) for years now and never figured what the hell is the keyboard shortcut for navigating forward/backward. I have tried a lot of different combination (including ['Ctrl' + '+'] or ['Ctrl' + '-'] but this did not work and after browsing several threads on the subject I never had the answer.
 **I must mention that I use an AZERTY french keyboard, maybe the shortcut is broken for this configuration?**

[image]

Comment: Check this answer please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040711/in-visual-studio-2012-what-is-the-navigate-backward-shortcut-on-a-french-keyboar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look in Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard for the shortcuts for `View.NavigateBackwards` and `View.NavigateForewards` (here, respectively, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>).